# Operations ($sum, $multiply, $push) on Decimal128 fields not working when using $unwind, $group

Tags: mongodb, azure-cosmosdb-mongoapi

I am using Azure Mongodb API 3.4, with the aggregation pipeline enabled.

I am trying to group my data for year-month and add a value in that group after multipying it by another value. When I run this on mongodb it works fine, but when I try to do it in Cosmos, I get this **error:**

```
> 2019-11-13T11:57:10.599-0300 E  QUERY    [js] uncaught exception:
> Error: command failed: {
>         "_t" : "OKMongoResponse",
>         "ok" : 0,
>         "code" : 115,
>         "errmsg" : "'Modification of Decimal128 not supported' is not supported",
>         "$err" : "'Modification of Decimal128 not supported' is not supported"
```

I don't understand why this is failing, and what work around I could use to achieve the same result.
**My data** looks like this:

```
> > db.myCollection.find().pretty() {
>         "_id" : ObjectId("5dc9b30727880d660c12be2e"),
>         "Created" : ISODate("2019-11-11T19:14:15.584Z"),
>         "MyCollection" : [
>                 {
>                         "DateField1" : ISODate("2019-11-11T00:00:00Z"),
>                         "DecimalValue1" : NumberDecimal("101")
>                 },
>                 {
>                         "DateField1" : ISODate("2019-11-12T00:00:00Z"),
>                         "DecimalValue1" : NumberDecimal("102")
>                 },
>                 {
>                         "DateField1" : ISODate("2019-11-13T00:00:00Z"),
>                         "DecimalValue1" : NumberDecimal("103")
>                 }
>         ] }
```

This is the **aggregation query I am using:**

```
db.myCollection.aggregate([
{ $unwind: "$MyCollection" },
{$group: {
        _id: {month : {$month : "$MyCollection.DateField1"}, 
          year : {$year :  "$MyCollection.DateField1"}}, 
        calculation: { $sum: { $multiply: [ 0.05, "$MyCollection.DecimalValue1" ] } }
    }},
    { $project: { month: "$id.month", year : "$id.year", calculation: "$calculation"},
])
```

I read the documentation and apparently, at least to my understanding, all the commands I am trying to use are supported by Cosmos. However if you remove `"$MyCollection.DecimalValue1"` from the equation, it works. Basically, if I use `0.05` instead of the field in the sum/multiply it doesn't fail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't find in the documentation anything saying that what I am trying to acomplish is not supported but it doesn't work.
I tried a workaround, instead of adding/multiplying my DecimalValue1 I tried pushing the number into an array so I could later, either on the projection or the server recalculate the value. However **this failed too, with the same error**. Which lead me to believe that even though they don't clarify it on the documentation, that I could find, these kind of operations with Decimals are not supported.

```
db.myCollection.aggregate([
{ $unwind: "$MyCollection" },
{$group: {
        _id: {month : {$month : "$MyCollection.DateField1"}, 
          year : {$year :  "$MyCollection.DateField1"}}, 
        test: { $push: "$MyCollection.DecimalValue1" }
    }},
    { $project: { month: "$id.month", year : "$id.year", test: "$test"},
])
```

However, I found a workaround. Instead of pushing the decimal value in the array, I push the whole field and then in the projection calculate the value. Surprisingly this worked. It is far from ideal, but I can't not find any other workaround to make it work in Cosmos.

```
db.myCollection.aggregate([
{ $unwind: "$MyCollection" },
{$group: {
        _id: {month : {$month : "$MyCollection.DateField1"}, 
          year : {$year :  "$MyCollection.DateField1"}}, 
        accumulatedItems: { $push: "$MyCollection" }
    }},
    { $project: { month: "$id.month", year : "$id.year", 
                  calculation : { $multiply: [ 0.05, { $test: "$accumulatedItems.DecimalValue1" } ] }},
])
```

Because of this issue, and several others where queries that worked fine in mongodb didn't work on Cosmos for no apparent reason we decided to switch to Atlas. Naturally, there my original query worked perfectly.

Comment: What is `{ $test: ... }` ? I don't see that operator in the docs. Also `$accumulatedItems.DecimalValue1` I don't see you adding that field? Are you missing a pipeline step in the middle?